# stop clear datatable search input while auto load data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i have one issue with jquery datatable. i am try to search record in table and its work perfect but my table record refresh every 5 seconds at that time if i type any characters in input box so it will search table record and fill related recode in table but when table data refresh every 5 second at that time datatable clear my search input and reload whole datatable

i want like if i search abc and find related record in table so do not clear input box while refresh data

here is my code for init datatable

```
table = $('#table').dataTable({
    data : Obj,
    destroy : true
});
```

please help me out for this issue

Comment: I'm guessing it's refreshing because you've got this in an Ajax success function. You've also got the 'destroy' option set, so this means that when the table is refreshed, the table is being destroyed, therefore the search text will also be destroyed as a result...

Comment: can you please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to have the Ajax within DataTables, and use that to reload the table, see the example below from this page on the DataTables [site](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  ajax: "data.json"
} );

setInterval( function () {
  table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. but my data is not static, it may change every time

Comment: Yep, that's what the table.ajax.reload() will do, it will get your new data, replacing the old.